# Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' error found in .NET Core xUnit test project when testing a .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, xunit

We have a new XUnit test .NET Core 2.x project which is testing a solution with .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects. When calling a log...

```
Log.Info(string.Format("Services - Begin...\nURL: {0} {1}\nREQUEST: {2}",postRequest.RequestUri, postRequest.subURL, postRequest.Body.BodyString), this);
```

... we are getting a Sitecore exception...

```
"The type initializer for 'Sitecore.DependencyInjection.DefaultSitecoreServicesConfigurator' threw an exception."
```

... with an inner exception which appears to the be crux of the issue.

```
{"Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.":"System.Web.HttpContextBase"}
```

Looking into it, it appears the only answer I get is that the System.Web.HttpContextBase is in a different system library between .NET Core and .NET Framework, but I could not find too much more information or how to solve it. I don't know how to force the unit test to use one or the other.

I cannot change .NET Framework projects at this time to .NET Core (we are implementing these tests so that we can fix it. Eventually, everything will become .NET Core, but for now I need to have this .NET Core testing project testing all the .NET Framework libraries and apps in the solution. If I remove that line of logging code (which we don't want to do), the tests actually work. What do I need to add or change in my xUnit .NET Core unit tests to get through these logging statements that fails our code?

For reference, here is my example test and some supporting code for context:

```
Hashtable servicesDelegatePaths = new Hashtable();

servicesDelegatePaths.Add("CheckChild", "web/do/CheckChildBelongsToParent/CheckChildBelongsToParent");

public void CheckChild_Success()
            {
                var restStatus = new RestStatus
                {
                    Status = new JsonResponseStatus
                    {
                        code = 200,
                        desc = "Record Matched",
                        key = ""
                    },
                    Data = "This is the reply data"
                };
                SetupRalAndHttpClient(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(restStatus));

                var response = ral.CheckChild("123456978", "Jim", "Smith", "1234", new DateTime(2010, 1, 1));

                Assert.NotNull(response.Result);
                Assert.NotNull(response.Result.Status);
                Assert.Equal(200, response.Result.Status.code);
                Assert.Equal("Record Matched", response.Result.Status.desc);
            }

    private void SetupRalAndHttpClient(string httpResponseMessageContentString)
            {
                var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
                handlerMock
                    .Protected()
                    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
                    {
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                        Content = new StringContent(httpResponseMessageContentString)
                    })
                    .Verifiable();
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object);
                ral = new RAL(domainURL, httpClient);
                ral.DelegatePaths = servicesDelegatePaths;
            }
```

Comment: HttpContextBase is not part of .net core. don't try to mix .net core and .net framework stuff

Comment: As I mentioned, I knew that much. What I need is to be able to safely remove it from our code or find the .net core equivalent for running unit tests.

Comment: We have decided on xUnit as an organization and xUnit is only available in .NET Core. I also cannot change over the projects until after we have inserted unit tests.

Comment: xunit does work in .net framework.

Comment: moving from asp.net core from asp.net is not simply flipping a switch. its a new paradigm that requires a rewrite.

Comment: How do I get my xunit project to be .net framework in vs 2019? I don't see any options to create an xunit framework project and I can't seem to find any extensions or downloads to allow me to create xunit framework. I have no options when creating a project for .net framework for xunit.

Comment: you'll have to read the xunit documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating, I could make an XUnit project in .net framework 4.6.x. It is relatively simple, but, for reference, here is a link. I can't believe I did not see this before.

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3168787/how-to-work-with-xunit-net-framework.html

With this, I can resolve all of the library issues and I was able to get the unit tests running.

Just as a note, you cannot directly create an XUnit project directly from the New Project menu in VS 2017 and 2019. You have to create a class library first and then add in the XUnit nuget packages you require.